# A tool to extract information from a Fibaro Virtual Device

Tags: lua

I am using Fibaro home automation. My HC2 (Home Centre 2) died unexpectedly. I had to migrate to HC3 (Home Centre 3) right away.

I had backups, but unfortunately a lot has changed. My last challenge is to convert dozens of Virtual Devices to Quick Apps. I can remember the UI, so I can recreate that easily, but the Lua code is another matter.

I  am looking for something that can extract the Lua code from VDs.